# Facebook marketing API Does not select the correct pixel conversion event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I'v built an app that creates ads using the marketing API. When it creates the adset it sets a specific pixel and a page view event.

All our users get the correct pixel and the correct event except for one user.

Here is the object from the post request that is being sent to Facebook where we can see that they are equal
User one

```
"promoted_object":"{\"pixel_id\":xxxxxxxxxx63,\"custom_event_type\":\"CONTENT_VIEW\",\"pixel_rule\":\"{\\\"event\\\":{\\\"eq\\\":\\\"PageView\\\"}}\"
```

User two

```
"promoted_object":"{\"pixel_id\":xxxxxxxxxx63,\"custom_event_type\":\"CONTENT_VIEW\",\"pixel_rule\":\"{\\\"event\\\":{\\\"eq\\\":\\\"PageView\\\"}}\"
```

Both get the correct pixel with the correct id but one gets no conversion event, and say Missing conversion event.

Both ad accounts have full access to the pixel under the business settings in ads manager.

Here is an image that describes the issue.
[image]

Anyone have any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

make sure the conversion event is defined in that account.

The conversion event is usually set on Campaign Level and supplied when you create a campaign via API.

As you're trying to use a custom conversion it might be that you've created it for one account but didn't create it for another. That's why you don't see it in you campaign setup view. You can create it via API as described here:

[Custom Conversion API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-conversion/)

Or just do it via Business Manager and use it afterward when creating you campaigns via API or manually.

It's definitely not a request that fails in this case but a proper account configuration.